# FB Messenger Bot & Heroku - Multiple Instances

Tags: facebook, heroku, bots, facebook-messenger-bot

I've developed a Facebook Messenger Bot using [BootBot](https://github.com/Charca/bootbot) and deployed it to a Heroku server.

My only issue is when multiple users start a conversation with the bot. Only a single instance of the bot is at any time available for all the users, meaning that if I create a global variable, its value will be accessible to all parts involved in the conversation.

I've managed to implement a workaround, by passing the facebook usedID around, but there must be something else that I could implement to have multiple instances of the bot, one for each user.

Am I right?

```
// Imports dependencies and set up http server
const 
  request = require('request'),
  express = require('express'),
  body_parser = require('body-parser');

const bot = new BootBot({
  accessToken: '',
  verifyToken: '',
  appSecret: ''
});

// ROUTING
bot.start(process.env.PORT || 3000);
    var path = require('path');
    bot.app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/test.html');
});
```

Comment: no, you have to identify users by their id and act accordingly, but bootbot should actually do that for you. why would you create a global var? what for exactly?

Comment: I have a very large flow of conversation lines, in which I'm gathering a file of information for each user. Let's say 2 users are in conversation with the bot at the same time, I want the files to be distinct... I would expect that by instantiating 2 different bot classes to keep the conversations separate....

Comment: bootbot supports conversation flows, according to the docs. you only presented a minimal amount of your code that is probably not even relevant for the question, hard to say what´s wrong, to be honest...

Comment: The conversations don't get mixed up, they work fine, because I'm using bot.conversation(userID, "Text"), and userID is passed from a method to another. But gathering information for each user by passing a user object from a method to another is not a good practice. I've seen other people saving data into a db accessible with the user fb id...

Comment: i don´t think it is bad practice, it´s how bots work anyway, so it´s more like a natural piping. much better than using global vars to store data, THAT would definitely be bad practice ;) - and of course, if you don´t store it "by user it", you will mix up user convos. you are starting ONE node server after all, not one per user.

Comment: Ok. I understand now. My expectations developing the bot were that somehow an instance of the bot would be created for each user. Thank you for clearing that up.